# Is it possible to use Mesos within the Google Container Engine?

Tags: mesos, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to run Spark on Mesos using the Google Container Engine.  Is it even possible to have this configuration?  If so, where do I find the information to get started?

Answer (score 1):

You can [run Kubernetes on top of Mesos](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.md), but it isn't currently possible to run Mesos on top of Kubernetes or Google Container Engine.